# J2ME push registry startup permission

Tags: java-me, permissions, push, midp, autostart

I made an application that uses Push Registry. When I try the application it does not work properly because of the permissions. Then I found out if I sign the application I can reach the `always allow` option.

But when I try application after signing at Samsung Omnia2 i8910, I click always allow then an alert come up saying it will change to only for this session. Anybody knows why this is? or how can I solve this?

Note: I use java verified R&D signing, and when I try to load at my Nokia 5800 it doesn't load because of certificate error. I don't know what I do wrong. I can load to Samsung.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I found an article about this problem. This problem occurs because of j2me security polities. J2ME doesn't allow to set always allow for auto start permission and network access. And that cannot be done with signing application. Article says that permissions are mutually exclusive.

"Additionally, the Blanket setting for Application Auto Invocation and the Blanket 
setting for Net Access are mutually exclusive. This constraint is to prevent a MIDlet 
suite from auto-invoking itself, then accessing a chargeable network without the user 
being aware. If the user attempts to set either the Application Auto Invocation or the 
Network Function group to "Blanket" when the other Function group is already in 
"Blanket" mode, the user MUST be prompted as to which of the two Function groups 
shall be granted "Blanket" and which Function group shall be granted "Session"."

ref: http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr118/MIDP_2.0.1_MR_addendum.pdf

Answer (score 1):

> Note: I use java verified R&D signing, and when I try to load at my Nokia 5800 it doesn't load because of certificate error. I don't know what I do wrong. I can load to Samsung.

R&D signed midlet should be run on device with rolled back date, because R&D certificate is given for 7 past days from the date of signing. For example: date of signing is 19.08.2012, work period is from 12.08.2012 to 18.08.2012